# Combine multiple rows into one single column (MS Access)

Tags: database-design, query, ms-access

I am trying to build a query from a table (Tbl_XYZ) that will give me the information for the primary key all in one row rather then creating dups for that primary key and showing up with multiple rows. Example below.( this is just a sample)

| Account Number(PK) | System_Name | Table_Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 012345 | DW | Customer |
| 012345 | DW | Sales |
| 012345 | DW | Address |
| 012345 | AWS | aws_Cust |
| 012345 | AWS | aws_product |

I was thinking about creating 2 separate tables for System_Name and Table_Name but it would still give me values in different rows since the table names are different.

My expectation :
( Of course, I will have to create separate queries for different system names (DW and AWS)

| Account Number | System_Name | Table_Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 012345 | DW | Customer / Sales / Address |
| 012345 | AWS | aws_Cust / aws_product |

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

I am using MS Access 2013

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2852892/10138734

Answer (score 0):

Access is not the most flexible DBMS, but I believe you have a function called STRING_AGG(), that you could use like:

```
select account_number, system_name, string_agg(isnull(table_name, ' '),'/ ') as table_name
from tbl_xyz group by account_number, system_name;
```